# Get All Secrets from Azure Key Vault with prefix

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I'd like to know if it is possible to get all Azure Key Vault Secrets by a prefix.

Let's say I have 3 secrets.

```
key: pre-secret1 
value: value1

key: secret2 
value: value2

key: pre-secret3
value: value3
```

I would like to get all secrets with a prefix pre and serialize them to JSON.
In the future, I will have more secrets with a prefix so I don't want to read by secret manually.
So when I add a new secret with a prefix, my function will return JSON with a new value as well.

The question is: is it possible to get secrets from Azure Key Vault by prefix and serialize dynamically to JSON?

Update: I would like to use it in ASP.NET Core 3.1 and C#.
Update2: I added how I can get one secret.

```
var client = new SecretClient(vaultUri: new Uri(kvUri), credential: new DefaultAzureCredential(true));
var secret = client.GetSecret("secret-name");
```

Comment: I have updated my post. I would like to use it in ASP.NET Core 3.1 and C#.

Comment: Can you not just add a wildcard to the name when querying secrets? Please show the code you currently have so we can help.

Comment: @RufusL I added how I can get one secret. There is no method to get secrets.

Comment: You might try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53499397/how-to-get-all-secrets-in-one-call-azure-key-vault

Comment: You need to get all secrets `await client.GetSecretsAsync(VaultUrl)`, filter it then serialize it. Seems to me you're abusing Key Vault for use cases it has never been designed to accommodate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use below code to achieve this. The `GetSecretsAsync` method gives you a dictionary of all the keys and secrets from the vault.

```
public async Task<IDictionary<string, string>> GetSecretsAsync(string vaultBaseUrl, string prefix = null, string keyVaultKeyDelimeter = "--", string configurationKeyDelimeter = ":")
            {
                // validation
                BaseUrlValidation(vaultBaseUrl);

            // variable declartion
            IDictionary<string, string> secretCollection = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            var updatedPrefix = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(prefix) ? prefix : $"{prefix}{keyVaultKeyDelimeter}";
            List<SecretItem> secretIdentifierCollection = new List<SecretItem>();

            // reading and adding secrets
            var secrets = await this.keyVaultClient.GetSecretsAsync(vaultBaseUrl).ConfigureAwait(false);
            string nextPageLink = secrets.NextPageLink;
            secretIdentifierCollection.AddRange(secrets);

            while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nextPageLink))
            {
                // reading and adding secrets
                var nextSecrets = await this.keyVaultClient.GetSecretsNextAsync(nextPageLink).ConfigureAwait(false);
                secretIdentifierCollection.AddRange(nextSecrets);
                nextPageLink = nextSecrets.NextPageLink;
            }

            if (!secretIdentifierCollection.Any())
            {
                return secretCollection;
            }

            // add filtered secrets to dictionary and remove prefix if any
            foreach (var secretId in FilterPrefixMatchingSecrets(updatedPrefix, secretIdentifierCollection))
            {
                await this.FetchSecretDetailsAsync(updatedPrefix, keyVaultKeyDelimeter, configurationKeyDelimeter, secretCollection, secretId);
            }

            return secretCollection;
        }

 private async Task FetchSecretDetailsAsync(string prefix, string keyVaultKeyDelimeter, string configurationKeyDelimeter, IDictionary<string, string> secretCollection, string secretId)
        {
            var secretDetails = await this.keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(secretId).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var secretName = secretDetails.SecretIdentifier.Name.Substring(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(prefix) ? 0 : prefix.Length).Replace(keyVaultKeyDelimeter, configurationKeyDelimeter);
            if (!secretCollection.ContainsKey(secretName))
            {
                secretCollection.Add(secretName, secretDetails.Value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do we still need to `.ConfigureAwait(false)` with .NET Core?

Comment: Yes, it is a best practice to always do that.

Comment: @HarshitaSingh No it’s not.  There’s no SynchronizationContext in .Net Core - https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html.  ConfigureAwait(false) is only really applicable if you’re writing library code.