# Sort secrets (categories) using Azure Key Vault

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-keyvault

I am currently facing an issue.
I want to create a web app using Azure keyvault to store data and c# (.NET Core Blazor). I managed to create secrets, list, delete them etc. But I can't seem to find a good way to filter secrets.

I first thought about using tags but then I noticed it wasn't their purpose.

Do you have any good ideas on how to do that ?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a c# or even a programming question. As of right now, Azure Key Vault doesn't have any way of tagging, categorizing, or grouping secrets (unless you are going to abuse the ContentType field). So until you can figure out how to use their product to do the thing you need to do, it's not worth talking about how to do it in code.

Comment: I guess, it was just to explain the context. I just noticed that we could filter key vaults by tags and that may solve my problem if I consider that a category (for example work) is represented by a keyvault, then when the user click on that category, i'll simply connect him to a different vault to do his operations. I'm wondering if that would work

Comment: You can use tags to group and sort the secrets any way you want. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/decision-guides/resource-tagging/?toc=/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/toc.json

Regarding some uses of tags:

Automation: In addition to making resources easier for IT to manage, a proper organizational scheme allows you to take advantage of automation as part of resource creation, operational monitoring, and the creation of DevOps processes.

Workload optimization: Tagging can help identify patterns and resolve broad issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it is **not possible**. There is a similar issue [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e870d2ee-1c61-4700-89a9-98398c32cf43/filtering-secrets-by-tag?forum=AzureKeyVault), and Azure support has explained. You could upvote the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/906355-azure-key-vault/suggestions/20369530-method-for-organising-secrets-in-key-vault-folder), but as azuresecretspm's comment, it seems still not possible.

> *Key Vault is designed for storing application secrets and cryptographic keys. It is not a database and should not be used like
> one. Search functions are not implemented. If you have large number of
> secrets to deal with, put those in a database and store the top level
> encryption key in key vault.*

It may be a workaround for you to change your secret names with different prefixes. And you can [get the specific secrets with prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64612280/get-all-secrets-from-azure-key-vault-with-prefix).

Comment: Yes the prefix idea seems good for me, i accepted as answer